# ¿Como obtengo los datos de un input de tipo array en ajax?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, array

tengo un proyecto de punto de venta y para los tickets (o comprobantes de pago), uso ajax. La cuestión es que hago la venta mediante php y al guardarla envío los datos por ajax a un script de php.

Aquí recojo los datos de la venta, para ahorrarme inputs de mas decidí meter los detalles del producto en un solo input de tipo array...

```
<form action="" id="ticketForm" method="post">
   <input type="hidden" name="vendedor" id="vendedor"  value="'.$this->_user['name'].' '.$this->_user['last_name'].'">';
   foreach ($this->show_tmt_items( $session_id ) as $items)
   {
      $output .= '<input type="hidden" name="todo[]" id="todo[]" value="'.$product['name'].'  '.$items['qty'].'   $'.number_format($_SESSION["Total"], 2, '.', ',').'">';
   }
   $output .= '
   <input type="hidden" value="'.$sub_total.'" id="totalventa" name="totalventa">
</form>
```

En mi archivo de javascript, tengo una función que hace la petición de ajax y otra que hace que se guarde la venta, El id del *#myForm* donde muestra la venta (o lo que se va a imprimir en el ticket).

```
swal({
   title: "Su cambio es: " + cambio + " Pesos",
   type: "warning",
   showCancelButton: true,
   confirmButtonClass: 'btn-warning',
   confirmButtonText: "Aceptar",
   closeOnConfirm: false
}, function () {
   $("#myForm").submit();
   ticket();
});

  function ticket() {
          var vendedor = document.getElementById('vendedor').value;
          var todo = document.getElementById('todo').value;
          var total_venta = document.getElementById('total').value;

          // JSON.stringify(todo);
          var data_send = 'vendedor='+vendedor+'&todo='+todo+'&total='+total_venta;
          alert(data_send);

          event.preventDefault();
          $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost/ImpresionTermica/ticket.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: data_send,
            success:function(resp){
              location.reload();
            }
          })
          return false;
        }
```

Ya trate de enviar los datos del form del ticket por post pero el total termina siendo el doble (seguramente se suman las variables), enviarlos por ajax es mi unica opcion segura, pero no se como recojer los datos del array ***todo[]*** e imprimirlos en php, necesito ayuda

Comment: No entiendo bien la lógica de tu código, Los inputs se crean dentro de un bucle, por lo que podrías estar creando varios inputs con el name `todo[]` ¿eso es lo que quieres?  Además le das el id `todo[]` a cada uno de ellos, pudiendo tener varios elementos con el mismo id, lo cual es incorrecto. Si explicas mejor lo que quieres hacer quizá se te pueda ayudar mejor. Esto es dudoso: *...para ahorrarme inputs de mas decidí meter los detalles del producto en un solo input de tipo array...* Creo que estás tomando un camino equivocado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que podrías usar es FormData para el envió de todo el contenido de tu formulario y así te evitas de estar armando tu arreglo de parámetros

ejemplo:
remplaza tu código por este

```
swal({
   title: "Su cambio es: " + cambio + " Pesos",
   type: "warning",
   showCancelButton: true,
   confirmButtonClass: 'btn-warning',
   confirmButtonText: "Aceptar",
   closeOnConfirm: false
}, function () {
   $("#myForm").trigger("submit");
});

$(document).on('submit','#myForm',function(){          
        // JSON.stringify(todo);
        var formElement = document.getElementById("ticketForm");
        var data_send = new FormData(formElement);//tambien puede ser FormData(this)
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost/ImpresionTermica/ticket.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: data_send,
            processData: false,
            success:function(resp){
            location.reload();
            }
        })

    });
```

y en php para recorrer todos

```
foreach($_POST["todo"] as $value)
{
 echo print_r($value);
}
```

Comment: Si funciona @Juan Carlos Hdz pero me aparece un mensaje que dice [Object: FormData], al parecer no tomo ningún dato e imprime el ticket en blanco

Comment: si es del lado javascript puedes utilizar JSON.stringify(data_send) o utilizar for each (var item in data_send)

Comment: Sigue sin tomarme los datos del FormData, te envié un correo para una mejor comunicación

Comment: tu problema esta en que haces el submit() y en seguida llamas la ticket(). una vez que se ejecuta el submit() se limpia,

Comment: actualice la respuesta